# How to implement a function that parses a string into a tuple?

Tags: python

Trying to create a function that parses a string measurement into a separated tuple measurement, i.e. `"3 ft"` into `(3, "ft")`.

Code:

```
def parse_measurement(measure_value: str) -> tuple:
    tuple_value = tuple(measure_value)
    return tuple_value

print(parse_measurement("3 ft"))
```

Output:

```
('3', ' ', 'f', 't')
```

Goal Output:

```
(3, "ft")
```

Is there an easier function for this that I'm totally missing? Or do I need to add additional code to remove the quotes, the extra space, and combine `'f'` and `'t'` to make `"ft"`?

Comment: `my_string.split()`?

Comment: Also, would the input always be `3 ft`, or could it have others, or maybe be part of a larger string, e.g. `measured 3 ft today` ?

Comment: As @Marat sugested, check [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) string method. Your code will probably look like `measure_value.split()` which will split it on the space between `3` and `ft`

Comment: This question doesn’t appear to use Python

Comment: @Marat and Felipe Whitaker, the .split(" ") worked, but resulted in the tuple ('3', 'ft'), how do I remove the quotes around the 3 and have double quotes around the ft? i.e. (3, "ft")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is the tuple `(3, "ft")` (with the `3` being a numeric value rather than a string, as your question seems to indicate), that will require a two-stage approach.

The first is to use `string.split` to separate the input string into a collection, and the second will be to modify the collection in such a way that strings representing integers are correctly *converted* to integers.

That can be done with:

```
def try_make_num(item):
    try:
        return int(item)
    except:
        return item

def parse_measurement(measure_value: str) -> tuple:
    return tuple([try_make_num(item) for item in measure_value.split()])

print(parse_measurement("3 ft")) # Gives (3, 'ft')
```

Note that this gives you the second field surrounded by *single* quotes, because that's the normal output format for strings. If you want a different format, you have to do that explicitly by replacing, for example, your current `print` with:

```
def desired_format(two_tuple):
    return f'({two_tuple[0]}, "{two_tuple[1]}")'

print(desired_format(parse_measurement("3 ft")))
```

But, of course, that gives you a single *string.* If you still want a tuple but with the string elements surrounded by double quotes, you can use:

```
def make_num_if_possible(item):
    try:
        return int(item)
    except:
        return f'"{item}"'
```

and get rid of `desired_format()`. Printing this tuple implicitly will give you `(3, '"ft"')` but processing of the individual elements will be correct if you explicitly print them.

Comment: That worked! Output still comes out as (3, 'ft') with only single quotes for me around ft. I truly appreciate your time helping.

Comment: @Corpo_Mantis, that's the default print format for a string, because there's no difference in Python between `'` and `"`. If you want the second as a `"`-string, you have to format it explicitly - I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Below code would help you

```
def parse_measurement(measure_value: str) -> tuple:
    tuple_value = tuple(measure_value.split(' '))
    return tuple_value
print(parse_measurement("3 ft"))
```

Output:

```
('3', 'ft')
```

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, you should at least indent it so that it works :-) Fixed it for you.

Comment: Thank you! To dig further, how would you remove the quotes around 3 and make them double quotes around the "ft"? Looks like this (3, "ft")

Comment: @Corpo_Mantis That is because you are directly printing the tuple like `print(tuple)`, what you do is iterate through the tuple and print its values, or simply `print(*tuple)`

Answer (score 1):

using `split()`

```
def parse_measurement(measure_value: str) -> tuple:
    # tuple_value = tuple(measure_value)
    return tuple(measure_value.split())
print(parse_measurement("3 ft"))

# ('3', 'ft')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_measurement(measure_value):
    return tuple(measure_value.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Tuple, List

def parse_measurement(measure_value: str, split_value: str=" ") -> Tuple:
    split_list: List[str] = measure_value.split(split_value)
    return tuple(split_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `.split` And convert and return tuple:

```
def parse_measurement(measure_value):
  return tuple(measure_value.split())
```

Hard-coded ' ' split is not required at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Input String** **"3 ft"** and your **Goal** is (3,"ft")

In general, you wanted to split string and type conversion of the values.

To solve for your input string :
we can simply split(" ") by spaces and then type convert.

Let's see how we can do this.

```py
string="3 ft"


def convert(s):
    try:
        return int(float(s)) if float(s) == int(float(s) else float(s)
    except:
        return s


res=tuple(map(convert, string.split(" "))

print(res)

You get your desired result.
Output:  (3,"ft")
```

**Now let's go more deep and change input to**

```py
string  = "set() b'1' True 3.1 3 (1,(1,(1,3),(1,3),(1,3),3)) [1,[1,4],[1,[1,[1,[1,4],4],4],4],3] {'a':{'a':{'a':{},'b':{'a':{},'b':{'a':{},'b':{'a':{},'b':{}}}}},'b':{}},'b':{'a':{},'b':{}}} ft"

# we have now string contains int, float, tuple of tuples, list of lists, nested dict, string,boolean, bytes and set. Almost Contains all the python literals.

# For that we need to determine the grammar, 
# we have Python abstract syntax grammar **ast**.
# We can evaluate list of strings that we split up using ast to determine and get string contains data of type converted to actual type. **Let's see how we can do this**

import ast 

def convert(a):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(a)
    except:
        return a

# By simply change convert function by ast.literal_eval(str)  
# Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. 
# Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

# This can be used for safely evaluating strings.

# **Note** set() is only supported in 3.9 and above.

# From above the **output** string is:
('set()', b'1', True, 'true', 3.1, 3, (1, (1, (1, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3), 3)), [1, [1, 4], [1, [1, [1, [1, 4], 4], 4], 4], 3], {'a': {'a': {'a': {}, 'b': {'a': {}, 'b': {'a': {}, 'b': {'a': {}, 'b': {}}}}}, 'b': {}}, 'b': {'a': {}, 'b': {}}}, 'ft')
```